# Search algorithm for the smallest index in a sequence of vectors matching predefined conditions

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, search

Let us presume we have **k** sequences of fixed length **p**. Each sequence has double values in range **0** to **1.0**. For simplicity let us also assume that the sequences are just arrays; in the real implementation, they will be list.

Now, the algorithm needs to find the smallest index the value of which represents a "major upset" in a given sequence. This upset can be a value of **1.0** or a value that goes over a certain threshold (e.g. **0.2**).  If, for example, moving from **j-1** to **j** the value increases over the threshold, then the index we seek would be **j-1**.

The upset of 1.0 takes precedence over the threshold value; for instance, if we find an index matching the threshold, we should still check the sequence for containing **1.0**.

Finally, the algorithm should produce the smallest index that resulted in the upset.
I have quickly put together some code to test the concept and show you the sort of thing I am after.  What I am looking for is a possibly more efficient implementation as this algorithm is going to be executed pretty extensively.

```
List<double[]> nearCaptures = new ArrayList<double[]>();
double threshold = 0.2;
double majorUpset = 1.0;
int[] indexes = new int[nearCaptures.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < nearCaptures.size(); i++) {
    int index = 0;
    double[] tempArray = nearCaptures.get(i);
    Arrays.sort(tempArray);
    int tempIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(tempArray, majorUpset);
    if (tempIndex > 0) {
        for (int j = 1; j < nearCaptures.get(0).length; j++) {
            if (nearCaptures.get(i)[j] == majorUpset) {
                index = j-1;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int j = 1; j < nearCaptures.get(0).length; j++) {
            if (nearCaptures.get(i)[j] >= nearCaptures.get(i)[j-1] + threshold) {
                index = j-1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    indexes[i] = index;
}
Arrays.sort(indexes);
System.out.println(indexes[0]);
```

Comment: I think that you actually might mean that an upset is constituted by an increase of a certain magnitude, not an increase over a threshold.  I dared not change this, though, as it changes the meaning of what you wrote.

Comment: There is a deeper meaning behind this threshold value which expresses a substantial increase in value, actually fitness value for a given chromosome. I am not sure whether this would be a magnitude of some value but rather constant indicating that very undesirable thing has happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some hints for improving performance (and correctness):

- When looking for a majorUpset, you perform a sort and a binary search, resulting in O(n log(n)) runtime, followed by a linear search (the for loop). That linear search would be all you need to find whether and where there is a majorUpset.
- Since `tempArray` refers to the original array, you mess up your indices when you sort it. If you needed to sort, sort a copy. But as noted above, you won't need to sort.
- You access the value `nearCaptures.get(i)` several times in a loop, where it would be better to store it in a local variable, right at the beginning of the `i`-loop.

**Addition:**

You might want to perform the search in parallel, because then you can stop as soon as you have found the smallest upset index in any of the arrays.

```
int p = nearCaptures.get(0).length;  // p is the common array length
// search for majorUpset
for(int j = 0; j < p; j++){
  for (double[] arr : nearCaptures) {
    if (arr[j]==majorUpset) return j; // first majorUpset
  }
}
// search for threshold
for(int j = 1; j < p; j++){
  for (double[] arr : nearCaptures) {
    if (arr[j]>arr[j-1]+threshold) return j-1; // first threshold
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, point taken about the lookup of majorUpset and allocation - thanks Christian. It was just a quick experimental code to see how to attack the issue. Done in a crude, brute force way.

Comment: You also should factor out the search code for a single array into a helper method. This increases readability of the code. And maybe replace the last `Arrays.sort(indexes)` with a linear search for the smallest element.

Comment: My addition suggest a different approach, which would make the other hints obsolete.

Comment: Ups! My addition is an answer to a different question. It does not return the index you are looking for.